# loading DOM using phantomjs

Tags: javascript, phantomjs

My html webpage has javascript that loads and applies stylesheets dynamically. All the content and rendering happens inside a div tag. This is not loading the contents of the div tag, which has the id = 'tagid'. Do you know what is wrong here? I am using jquery function to ensure that the page is loaded. But is seems page.evaluate is not even called.

I am writing unit tests using phantomjs. New to the phantomjs. Refer to the code snippet below.

```
page.open(address, function(status){
    console.log('status '+status)
    if(status=='success'){
        console.log('inside status if ')
        page.includeJs("http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js", function() {
            console.log('after include js ')
            page.evaluate(function(){
                console.log('inside evlaute ')
                $(window).load(function(){
                    console.log(document.getElementById("tagid").innerHTML)

                });
            });

            setTimeout(function(){phantom.exit()},18000)
        })
    }
})
```

Comment: Calling `$(window).load(...)` after the page is loaded doesn't make sense. The callback will never be called.

Answer (score 1):

Your code is correct, but the `console.log` call does not have any effect by default as it happens in the PhantomJS page's context.

You can either use the return value of the `evaluate` call as follows:

```
page.includeJs("http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js", function() {
  console.log('after include js ')
  var tagid = page.evaluate(function(){
    console.log('inside evlaute ')
    return document.getElementById("tagid").innerHTML;
  });

  console.log('Got tag ID: ' + tagId)
  setTimeout(function(){phantom.exit()},18000)
})
```

Or you can choose to display messages that are logged in the page by using [`onConsoleMessage`](http://phantomjs.org/api/webpage/handler/on-console-message.html) (more complicated setup):

```
page.onConsoleMessage = function(msg, lineNum, sourceId) {
  console.log('PAGE CONSOLE: ' + msg + ' (from line #' + lineNum + ' in "' + sourceId + '")');
};
```

**An important note** is that PhantomJS and page's context are separate: inside `evaluate` calls, you can't access variables from outside. In fact, under the hood, the callback given to `evaluate` is converted to a string before being given to the `page`. This is a very confusing part of PhantomJS that must be considered.

Comment: Thanks blint. I tried returning the tagid in the evaluate function. But that seems to give some error. The console output is as follows:                                     -------------------------------------------                                                                                                          status success
inside status if 
after include js 
TypeError: null is not an object (evaluating 'document.getElementById("tagid").innerHTML')

  undefined:2
  :3
--------------------------------------------------

Comment: Looks like you have no element with id `tagid` in your page (at the moment of evaluate = right after the page has loaded). If this element is rendered later by a script, you could use a `setInterval` to check periodically when `#tagid` is appended to the DOM before proceeding to the next steps.

Answer (score 0):

You could try by giving some timeout before you call evaluate.

```
window.setTimeout(function () {
    page.evaluate(function() {
         console.log(document.getElementById("tagid").innerHTML)
    });
}, 1000 // adjust the time here
```

To check what content is being rendered in phantomjs, you can use `page.content` and check there if your "tagid" element is indeed present.

Comment: thanks Artjom. Looks like tagid element is present but no content visible to phantomjs. But when i use chrome developer tools to load the page.. i do see the content is rendered. The content of tagid are rendered in the html at runtime. What could be happening?